# Global revision without locking

Tags: sql, concurrency, transactions, locking

Given this set of rules, would it be possible to implement this in SQL?

1. Two transactions that don't modify the same rows should be able to run concurrently. No locks should occur (or at least their use should be minimized as much as possible).
2. Transactions can only read committed data.
3. A revision is defined as an integer value in the system.
4. A new transaction must be able to increment and query a new revision. This revision will be applied to every rows that the transaction modifies.
5. No 2 transactions can share the same revision.
6. A transaction X that is committed before transaction Y must have a revision lower than the one assigned to transaction Y.

I want to use integer as the revision in order to optimize how I query all changes since a specific revision. Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM [DummyTable] WHERE [DummyTable].[Revision] > clientRevision
```

My current solution uses an SQL table [GlobalRevision] with a single row [LastRevision] to keep the latest revision. All my transactions' isolation level are set to Snapshot.

The problem with this solution is that the [GlobalRevision] table with the single row [LastRevision] becomes a point of contention. This is because I must increment the revision at the start of a transaction so that I can apply the new revision to the modified rows. This will keep a lock on the [LastRevision] row throughout the duration of the transaction, killing the concurrency. Even though two concurrent transactions modify totally different rows, they cannot be executed concurrently (Rule #1: Failed).

Is there any pattern in SQL to solve this kind of issue? One solution is to use Guids and keep an history of revisions (like git revisions) but this is less easier than just having an integer that we can compare to see if a revision is newer than another one.

**UPDATE:**

The business case for this is to create a Baas system (Backend as a service) with data synchronization between client and server. Here are some use cases for this kind of system:

- Client while online modifies an asset, pushes the update to the server, server updates DB [**this is where my question relates to**], server sends update notifications to interested clients that synchronize their local data with the new changes.
- Client connects to server, client requests a pull to the server, server finds all changes that were applied after client's revision and return them to the client, client applies the changes and sets its new revision.
- ...

As you can see, the global revision lets me put a revision on every changes committed on the server and from this revision, I can determine what updates need to be sent to the clients depending on their specific revision.

This needs to scale to multiple thousands of users that can push updates in parallel and those changes must be synchronized to other connected users. So the longer it takes to execute a transaction, the longer it takes for other users to receive the change notifications.

I want to avoid as much as possible contention for this reason. I am not an expert in SQL so I just want to make sure there is not something I am missing that would let me do that easily.

Comment: Have to ask....why are you set on having no locks ?   ( or as you say, should be minimized as much as possible, and...how little...is little enough ?  )         There is on one hand a lot of detailed constraints and on the other, this rather stark ambiguity.        It would probably help a great deal to describe the business problem you are facing...not just the solution constraints that you desire.

Comment: @Juan-Carlos, Fair enough, I updated the question to give more context. Let me know if it's clearer for you or if you need more info!

Comment: Absolom, that helps a lot.  Your concern for lock delays is understandable.  Will study the problem with this new insight in hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest thing for you to try would be to use a [`SEQUENCE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx) for your revision number, assuming you're at SQL 2012 or newer.  This is a lighter-weight way of generating an auto-incrementing value that you can use as a revision ID per your rules.  Acquiring them at scale should be far less subject to the contention issues you describe than using a full-fledged table.

You do need to know that you could end up with revision number gaps if a given transaction rolled back, because `SEQUENCE` values operate outside of transactional scope.  From the article:

> Sequence numbers are generated outside the scope of the current
>   transaction. They are consumed whether the transaction using the
>   sequence number is committed or rolled back.

If you can relax the requirement for an integer revision number and settle for knowing what the data was at a given point in time, you might be able to use [Change Data Capture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645937.aspx), or, in SQL 2016, [Temporal Tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dn935015.aspx).  Both of these technologies allow you to "turn back time" and see what the data looked like at a known timestamp.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'll have a look at these options and see if they can help for my use case.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!